# Nginx (using mod_zip) un-escaping URL input

Tags: url, nginx, escaping

## Background

I am using Nginx with mod_zip (http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxZip, on Github [here](https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip)) as a proxy to stream data from Amazon's S3 into an archive.

mod_zip takes a manifest of space-separated arguments. Newlines delimit new files.
The format for each line is:
`CRC[- for unknown] size location filename`

**Example of a two-line manifest**:

```
- 4 /pro-core.com/prostore/9228407_foobar.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Expires=sometime&Signature=signed foo/foobar.txt
- 288134 /pro-core.com/prostore/9228400_38.png?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Expires=soon&Signature=signed bar/38.png
```

This would create an archive with 2 directories:

```
|- foo
|   |- foobar.txt
|- bar
    |- 38.png
```

**My nginx.conf file**:

> user nginx;
>
> worker_processes  1;
>
> error_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log debug;
>
> events {
>       worker_connections  1024;
>   }
>
> http {
>       include       mime.types;
>       default_type  application/octet-stream;
>
> ```
> #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
>
> keepalive_timeout  0;
> sendfile off;
> gzip  off;
>
> server {
>     listen       8008;
>     server_name  localhost;
>
>     #charset koi8-r;
>
>     #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
>
>     root html;
>
>     location / {
>         internal;
>     }
>
>     location /pro-core.com/ {
>         internal;
>         proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com;
>         proxy_buffering off;
>         proxy_buffers 2 4m;
>         proxy_buffer_size 4m;
>         proxy_busy_buffers_size 4m;
>     }
>
>     location /download/ {
>         proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/utilities/s3_manifest_for_nginx_to_zip_and_stream/;
>         proxy_redirect off;
>         proxy_buffering off;
>         proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
>         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
>         proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding identity;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

## Problem

mod_zip seems to do something funny with parentheses. Some of my S3 keys have parentheses in them, like `9228403_foobar (1).txt`. I cannot change the S3 keys. In the manifest, I have a line that looks like:

```
- 4 /pro-core.com/prostore/9228403_foobar%20%281%29.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Expires=time&Signature=signed foo/foobar _1_.txt
```

Notice the location URL is escaped. When I try and open the resulting archive, it is corrupt. Sad panda. Looking at the nginx error log, I am getting a 403 from S3 for the file with parens in the key:

**From nginx log**:

```
"GET /pro-core.com/prostore/9228403_foobar%20(1).txt?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Expires=time&Signature=signed HTTP/1.0
...
[debug] : *31 http proxy status 403 "403 Forbidden"
```

Notice that the parens in the location URL are no longer escaped.
I verified that the URL was the problem by performing a vanilla "GET" via curl.

```
$ curl -v http://s3.amazonaws.com/..._foobar%20(1).txt?...
=> 403 Forbidden -- SignatureDoesNotMatch

$ curl -v http://s3.amazonaws.com/..._foobar%20%281%29.txt?...
=> 200 OK -- contents of foobar (1).txt
```

## Question

Is there any way to change something in my app, or tell nginx or mod_zip to not un-escape my URLs?

Comment: Are your curl requests sent to amazon or your own nginx server? If these requests are sent to your nginx server, then the issue is the request that should be encoded in the first place. To have a fair comparison, I would send the curl requests to both amazon and the nginx server to see if I get different response.

Comment: The curls were sent to amazon. I'm having trouble curl-ing directly to nginx, since my application uses it as a proxy to S3. I've updated my question to clarify the curl output.

Comment: Based on your nginx config 

     `proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com;`

nginx shall pass the original $request_uri to the upstream server. So the most possible case is that the bad un-escaping happens in your app server.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how mod_zip handles my application's response (the manifest containing S3 URLs). I can verify that my app generates a properly-escaped URL before it is passed to nginx. What mod_zip/nginx does with it afterwards is a black box to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for my issue, which is to remove parentheses from my S3 keys. It's not ideal, but it solves our problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx will decode the uri that is passed to the proxy pass and so break your calls to s3.

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.